# Fetch data from API in React and visualize it using Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, charts

I've created an API in Node.js. I want to visualize the fetched data as Bar Chart from API and visualize it in React using Chart.js.

I've come across on how to visualize the static data in chart.js using React. But I want to visualize the data received from API.

I've tried:

**API.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Chart from './chart';
class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            chartData:{}
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.getchartData();
    }
    async getchartData(){
        //Ajax Calls here
        await fetch('http://localhost:8000/data')
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(res=>this.setState({chartData:{apiResponse:res}}))
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="App">
                <div className="App-header">
                    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
                </div>
                <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**Chart.js::**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Bar,Line,Pie} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Chart extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            chartData:props.chartData
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="chart">
            <Bar 
                data={this.state.chartData}
                options={{}}
        )
    }
}

export default Chart;
```

**My data in API looks as::**

```
[{"_id":"","TotalStudents":"123","TotalTeachers":"233","TotalStaffs":"433"}]
```

I want to visualize the data from the fetched api. Any suggestion will be helpful as I'm new to react and chart.js. Also I've skipped the static data with which the chart was generated. In case it's needed please do tell. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure what if your `<Bar />` component looks like inside.
My preferable way (mostly used) is to create Chart instance with the `ref` and draw that ref with the `canvas` tag.
So it can render canvas with chart ref.

Here is the snippet.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Chart from "chart.js";

export default class LineGraph extends Component {
    chartRef = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        this.buildChart();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.buildChart();
    }

    buildChart = () => {
        const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");
        const { data, average, labels } = this.props;

        if (typeof myLineChart !== "undefined") myLineChart.destroy();

        myLineChart = new Chart(myChartRef, {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                //Bring in data
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Sales",
                        data: data,
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: "#6610f2"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "National Average",
                        data: average,
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: "#E0E0E0"
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                //Customize chart options

            }
        });
    }
```

You can pass data when you create a Chart instance.

e.g. `datasets:[ { label: "", data: this.props.chartData } ]`

I have implemented this way and used in several project.
I followed this article and super helpful.
https://blog.bitsrc.io/customizing-chart-js-in-react-2199fa81530a

Comment: But the thing here is I want to fetch data from API as mentioned in my question. And you have provided for static data which I have already implemented using above code in quesion.

Comment: What I meant in this snippet is that you can pass data from parent component.

Comment: If your chart instance is not updated with the data which is passed from API call, you need to use `componentDidUpdate` to update instance.
I updated the answer.